# É possível fazer um color picker com canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, cores

Com a adição do `canvas` no HTML5, várias possibilidades surgiram, como criação de pequenos joguinhos ou até um gerador de memes.

Com isso, gostaria de saber se através do `canvas` seria possível fazer a criação de um color picker.

Vejo muitas implementações de color picker por aí, (já até tentaram fazer o `input[type=color]`, mas não estou certo quanto a compatibilidade).

Se for possível, queria fosse próximo disso:

[image: Color picker com canvas]

Answer (score 3):

Tem várias até, algumas interessantes:

- [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/amwill/pen/ZbdGeW)
- [seesparkbox.com](https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/how_i_built_a_canvas_color_picker)
- [github](https://gist.github.com/lovasoa/8141243)

O que achei sacado foi para gerar a paleta de cores (pedaço do código do link do codepen):

```
// esse elemento é um canvas
var colorStrip = document.getElementById('color-strip');
var ctx2 = colorStrip.getContext('2d');
var width2 = colorStrip.width;
var height2 = colorStrip.height;

// desenha o retângulo
ctx2.rect(0, 0, width2, height2);
var grd1 = ctx2.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height1);
// desenha cada parte corresponde à paleta de cores
grd1.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)');
grd1.addColorStop(0.17, 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)');
grd1.addColorStop(0.34, 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)');
grd1.addColorStop(0.51, 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)');
grd1.addColorStop(0.68, 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)');
grd1.addColorStop(0.85, 'rgba(255, 0, 255, 1)');
grd1.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)');
ctx2.fillStyle = grd1;
ctx2.fill();
```

```js
var colorBlock = document.getElementById('color-block');
var ctx1 = colorBlock.getContext('2d');
var width1 = colorBlock.width;
var height1 = colorBlock.height;

var colorStrip = document.getElementById('color-strip');
var ctx2 = colorStrip.getContext('2d');
var width2 = colorStrip.width;
var height2 = colorStrip.height;

var colorLabel = document.getElementById('color-label');

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var drag = false;
var rgbaColor = 'rgba(255,0,0,1)';

ctx1.rect(0, 0, width1, height1);
fillGradient();

ctx2.rect(0, 0, width2, height2);
var grd1 = ctx2.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height1);
grd1.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)');
grd1.addColorStop(0.17, 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)');
grd1.addColorStop(0.34, 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)');
grd1.addColorStop(0.51, 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)');
grd1.addColorStop(0.68, 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)');
grd1.addColorStop(0.85, 'rgba(255, 0, 255, 1)');
grd1.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)');
ctx2.fillStyle = grd1;
ctx2.fill();

function click(e) {
  x = e.offsetX;
  y = e.offsetY;
  var imageData = ctx2.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
  rgbaColor = 'rgba(' + imageData[0] + ',' + imageData[1] + ',' + imageData[2] + ',1)';
  fillGradient();
}

function fillGradient() {
  ctx1.fillStyle = rgbaColor;
  ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, width1, height1);

  var grdWhite = ctx2.createLinearGradient(0, 0, width1, 0);
  grdWhite.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
  grdWhite.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255,255,255,0)');
  ctx1.fillStyle = grdWhite;
  ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, width1, height1);

  var grdBlack = ctx2.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height1);
  grdBlack.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
  grdBlack.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,1)');
  ctx1.fillStyle = grdBlack;
  ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, width1, height1);
}

function mousedown(e) {
  drag = true;
  changeColor(e);
}

function mousemove(e) {
  if (drag) {
    changeColor(e);
  }
}

function mouseup(e) {
  drag = false;
}

function changeColor(e) {
  x = e.offsetX;
  y = e.offsetY;
  var imageData = ctx1.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
  rgbaColor = 'rgba(' + imageData[0] + ',' + imageData[1] + ',' + imageData[2] + ',1)';
  colorLabel.style.backgroundColor = rgbaColor;
}

colorStrip.addEventListener("click", click, false);

colorBlock.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown, false);
colorBlock.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup, false);
colorBlock.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove, false);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
h2 {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
#color-input {
  display: none;
}
#color-label {
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
} 
#color-input:checked ~ #color-picker {
  opacity: 1;
}
#color-picker {
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px; 
  background-color: white;
  height: 150px;
  width: 185px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
canvas:hover {
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<p>Referencia: https://codepen.io/amwill/pen/ZbdGeW</p>

<label for="color-input" id="color-label" style="background-color: red"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="color-input" checked></input>

<div id="color-picker">
  <canvas id="color-block" height="150" width="150"></canvas>
  <canvas id="color-strip" height="150" width="30"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 Essa edição não foi Pontual =)

Comment: :D pois é verdade, por sorte o código ainda estava lá, agora preservado aqui tbm